# Combobox added to datagridview losses its selection

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I am trying to populate a datagrid table and add an additional combobox in a Winforms application to allow the user to select from an exception list.

The datagrid is populated using a Stored Procedure on SQL server.
(NOTE: due to my ITs security I have to go through a single server using linked servers to where the data is to query the data so the stored procedure uses dynamic SQL)

The data pulls properly and the additional combobox appears however once I select an exception on 1 row and try to go to the next row, the first combobox's selection disappears.

An additional question, given the nature or how I query the data, how would I update the data on the original sql tables from datagrid?  Another stored procedure?

FYI, I'm a SQL developer but I'm fairly new to C#

My code is below for the datagridview method.  Thanks in advance.

```
    public void displayDataGridView(string param)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = SQLServer1; initial catalog=GlbDBNames; integrated security=true ");

        {   
            SqlCommand cmd;
            cmd = new SqlCommand(param, con);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 60 * 20;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dg_batchsummary.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dg_batchsummary.Columns[0].Width = 200;
            dg_batchsummary.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dg_batchsummary.AllowUserToAddRows = false;


             DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ExceptionList = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
             ExcptionList.HeaderText = "Exception List";
             ExceptionList.Name = "Newexcept";
             ExceptionList.Items.AddRange("Item1","Item2","Item3");

             dg_batchsummary.Columns.Add(ExceptionList);
        }
```

Comment: I *think* your question is "Why does my combobox selection change when I select a new row in the datagridview?"  Is that correct?

Comment: The selection doesn't change exactly.  The exception I choose in row #1 (i.e "Item2") will disappear/revert to a null status when I click on Row #2 to choose an exception there.

Comment: are you refreshing the datagridview at all during that process?

Comment: No.  I use a button click to pass the stored procedure parameter into the method and populate the datagridview and add the new combobox

Comment: If I make a brand new winforms project and do this: `DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            t.Columns.Add("Column1");
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgv.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                t.Rows.Add(i);
            }
            dgv.DataSource = t;` and then use your code to add the combobox column it works.... do you have any events hooked up? what else happens in your code?

Comment: The form doesnt do much else.  It has 2 combo boxes for the user to query a subset of data.  Once they select those options, they press the G Data button which collects the parameters, the combobox selections into the param string which calls the displayDataGridView method.   The param contains the EXEC usp_storedprocedure with the parameters chosen and populates the dataset which fills the datagridview.  The new combo box is added then.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's because I'm using a stored procedure to populate the dataset instead of an actual table

Comment: shouldn't matter, but you can try using some static data (instead of the SP + database) and see if you get the same result. isolate each point of potential problem and try to find it...

Comment: That's for the suggestion Drew.  I created a new solution to test on a static database and it works and updates properly.  I'll change the SPROC to create a static table to store the data and then fill the datagridview from there.  Thanks for your help